# cabal sandbox + haskeline

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal install haskeline
... installs successfully ...

ghci
Prelude> :module +System.Console.Haskeline

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `System.Console.Haskeline'

ghc-pkg list haskeline
.. not found ..
```

What do I have to do get haskeline to work with cabal sandbox?  If I install haskeline normally (no sandbox) it is fine (ghc-pkg list haskeline -- found it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `cabal repl` like Joseph mentioned or you can explicitly pass the package db to the GHCi shell relative to your current working directory.

```
ghci -no-user-package-db -package-db .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d YourModule.hs
```

It's recommended that you just use cabal.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get `ghci` to use a local sandbox you must (a) set up a `my-project.cabal` file and (b) use `cabal repl`.